# touchmove coordinates delay when scrolling

Tags: html, mobile, browser, scroll, touchmove

The coordinates seem to read fine on a desktop/laptop browser. However on mobile, I'm getting a delay while scrolling/swiping down and up. The coordinates seem to be jumpy and not updating immediately.

If you try on desktop and mobile you'll see difference. I wonder if this is a bug, or there is some way to make it follow the touch better. Can anyone help?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>mobile XY</title>
        <style>
        html, body {
            overscroll-behavior: none;
        }
        .xy {
            position:fixed;
            touch-action: none;
            pointer-events: none;
            transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
            z-index: 10001;
        }
        .spacer {
            height: 700px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="xy"></div>
        <div class="spacer">spacer 1</div><div class="spacer">spacer 2</div><div class="spacer">spacer 3</div><div class="spacer">spacer 4</div><div class="spacer">spacer 5</div>
        <script>
            function showCoordinates(event){
                var x, y;
                if (event.type === 'touchmove' || event.type === 'touchstart' || event.type === 'touchend') {
                    var touch = event.touches[0];
                    x = touch.clientX;
                    y = touch.clientY;
                } else {
                    x = event.clientX;
                    y = event.clientY;
                }
                document.querySelector('.xy').textContent = 'X: ' + x + ', Y: ' + y;
                document.querySelector('.xy').style.left = x + "px";
                document.querySelector('.xy').style.top = y + "px";
            }
            ['mousemove', 'touchmove', 'touchstart', 'touchend'].forEach(eventType => document.addEventListener(eventType, showCoordinates));
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```